# Fatal error: Smarty error: ... syntax error: unrecognized tag 'var'

Tags: php, smarty

Ошибка при установке скрипта. При установке выдает такую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in deposit.tpl line 74]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'var' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 553) in /home/finansin/[finans-invest.com/www/inc/libs/Smarty.class.php](http://finans-invest.com/www/inc/libs/Smarty.class.php) on line 1102

Что она означает?

Comment: @Александр Гижевский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быть может ты используешь в tpl JS код в котором есть символы {}

Лучше JS код поместить в такие теги

```
 {literal}<script>тут код</script>{/literal}
```